# Shopify Add Custom field to Collection Page in Admin

Tags: shopify

Hello Shopify Developers.

I'm a newbie on Shopify. I want to build a menu just like http://www.nastygal.com/. It shows menu items and featured products in menu area.

Would you give me a suggestion how to make a menu like this?

I'm not sure this is the best idea, though I think that I can create special collections to assign menus. I want to add a custom field in collection page to assign category to special menu. I noticed that I may use meta-fields for this but not sure.

How to add meta-fields to description fields in collection admin page?

How to get values from meta-fields in front page?

I'm open for suggestions, please teach me.

Best regards, Lorant.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there was a couple of steps to making this work, but it shouldn't be hard.

1. Create a collection that contains the products in it that you would like to show in the menu.
2. In your navigation link list create a link that points to collection you want to show in the menu. Call it something like `show-products`.

The menu liquid would look something like this:

```
{% assign linklist = linklists.main-menu %}
{% for link in linklist %}
  {% if link.title == 'show-products' and link.type == 'collection_link' %}
    {% assign menu_collection = link.object %}
    {% for menu_product in menu_collection.products %}
      {{ menu_product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'compact' | img_tag: menu_product.title }}
      {{ menu_product.title }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    {% include 'my-normal-menu-link' with link %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: this code is untested, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.